# Is there a way to update cached in-memory value on all running instance of a serverless function? (AWS,Google,Azure or OpenWhisk)

Tags: aws-lambda, google-cloud-functions, azure-functions, serverless, openwhisk

Suppose I am running a serverless function with a global state variable which is cached in memory. Assuming that the value is cached on multiple running instances, how an update to the global state would be broadcasted to every serverless instance with the updated value?

Is this possible in any of the serverless framework?

Comment: For the cloud functions that I have worked with (AWS, Alibaba, Azure, Google) you can't unless you have written code in your function to do so. The only trick is to redeploy which will force each function instance to terminate so that a restart recreates the global state. Hint, design your functions to be stateless.

Comment: @JohnHanley Thank you, what do you mean by unless you have written code in your function? Is it possible to address each instance via some code written inside the function?

Comment: That means you have written some code that is triggered by an action you take such as specifying an HTTP header, query parameter, URI, etc. that your code detects and then does something special such as updating the global state.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on the serverless framework you're using, which makes it hard to give a useful answer on Stack Overflow. You'll have to research each of them. And you'll have to review this over time because their underlying implementations can change.

In general, you will be able to achieve your goal as long as you can open up a bidirectional connection from each function instance so that your system outside the function instances can send them updates when it needs to. This is because you can't just send a request and have it reach every backing instance. The serverless frameworks are specifically designed to not work that way. They load balance your requests to the various backing instances. And it's not guaranteed to be round robin, so there's no way for you to be confident you're sending enough duplicate requests for each of the backing instances to have been hit at least once.

However, there is something also built into most serverless frameworks that may stop you, even if you can open up long lives connections from each of them that allow them to be reliably messaged at least once each. To help keep resources available for functions that need them, inactive functions are often "paused" in some way. Again, each framework will have its own way of doing this.

For example, OpenWhisk has a configurable "grace period" where it allows CPU to be allocated only for a small period of time after the last request for a container. OpenWhisk calls this pausing and unpausing containers. When a container is paused, no CPU is allocated to it, so background processing (like if it's Node.js and you've put something onto the event loop with `setInterval`) will not run and messages sent to it from a connection it opened will not be responded to.

This will prevent your updates from reliably going out unless you have constant activity that keeps every OpenWhisk container not only warm, but unpaused. And, it goes against the interests of the folks maintaining the OpenWhisk cluster you're deploying to. They will want to pause your container as soon as they can so that the CPU it consumed can be allocated to containers not yet paused instead. They will try to tune their cluster so that containers remain unpaused for a duration as short as possible after a request/event is handled. So, this will be hard for you to control unless you're working with an OpenWhisk deployment you control, in which case you just need to tune it according to your needs.

Network restrictions that interfere with your ability to open these connections may also prevent you from using this architecture.

You should take these factors into consideration if you plan to use a serverless framework and consider changing your architecture if you require global state that would be mutated this way in your system.

Specifically, you should consider switching to a stateless design where instead of caching occurring in each function instance, it occurs in a shared service designed for fast caching, like Redis or Memcached. Then each function can check that shared caching service for the data before retrieving it from its source. Many cloud providers who provide serverless compute options also provide managed databases like these. So you can often deploy it all to the same place.

Also, you could switch, if not to a stateless design, a pull model for caching instead of a push model. Instead of having updates pushed out to each function instance to refresh their cached data, each function would pull fresh data from its source when they detect that the data stored in their memory has expired.